Save vector layer as excel in Qgis graphical moduler
I have made a model in QGIS graphical modeler builder that outputs multiple vector layers. Each vector layer has data i need in excel. I would like to put them all in preferably one excel file ( each layer on a different sheet).
How do i save the layers automatically in excel using the graphical modeler builder and combine them in one excel.
I tried to save as worksheet but that didn't work, also don't know how to combine multple layers into one excel
At the moment i manually right click save as xlsx every vector layer and then copy paste them in one.

there's an algorithm that do that "Export to spreadsheet" in Qgis.

How would that algorithm work to do what the question asks: using multiple sheets

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

In the graphical modeler you can use the algorithm "Export to spreadsheet" and if you choose the input type "123" you can select all the inputs that you want to export in the spreadsheet (algorithms outputs or inputs). Each input will be in a separate tab.
